# Can someone merge these two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can someone merge [lens-coatings](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens-coatings) tag and [lenscoat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenscoat) tag as I believe they have the same meaning?

Comment: Lenscoat is currently used for http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/has-anyone-used-the-lenscoat-for-the-canon-ef-100-400mm-l-zoom-lens/ and one other question, both of which are about a product named "LensCoat" (a case for lenses), as opposed to a lens coating.  Not that I think a product necessarily needs its own tag, but these tags are for different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lenscoat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenscoat) is currently used on questions relating to a product named "LensCoat" (a case for lenses), as opposed to coatings to the surfaces of lenses; as such it doesn't appear to be the right thing to do at the moment.